# when I run the notebook, without any results, where is my mistakes?please help

Tags: equation-solving, code-review

```
ClearAll; 
R1 = 4.25; R2 = 3.85; 
h = 0.4; b = 1.6; a = 0.05; 
jiaodu = 56.8421*(Pi/180); 
g = 9.8; 
L1 = 2.026; L2 = 1.833; 
GS = 6.7*1000*g; GP = 38.4*g; 
xin = -((2*(Cos[jiaodu/2] - 1)*(R1^3 - R2^3))/(3*
       jiaodu*(R1^2 - R2^2))); 
FX = ((3*GS + 6*GP)*L1)/(2*Sqrt[4*R2^2 - L1^2]); FY = (3*GS + 6*GP)/2; 
M1 = FX*(R2 - Sqrt[R2^2 - L1^2/4] + h/2) + 
  FY*(L1/2); M2 = ((4*GS + 6*GP)*L2)/4; M3 = (xin*GS)/2; 
MF = M1 - M2 + M3; 
NF = FX; 
Iz = (b*h^3)/12; 
σ1 = (MF/Iz)*(h/2); 
σ2 = NF/(b*h); 
σ = σ1 - σ2; 
If[σ > 0, Print["正负三角分布"]]
Eci = 39.7*10^9; Null; 
Ec1 = 24.7*10^9; Null; 
εc1 = -2.6/10^3; 
εclim = -3.4/10^3; 
fcm = 63*10^6; 
εc = x*\[Beta]; 
η = εc/εc1; 
k = Eci/Ec1; 
σc = (-fcm)*((k*η - η^2)/(1 + (k + 2)*η)); 
Fcp = Integrate[σc*b, {x, 0, x0}]; 
MFcp = Integrate[σc*b*x, {x, 0, x0}]; 
εct = x*β; 
EC0αE = 19400*10^6; 
Eci = EC0αE*(fcm/(10*10^6))^(1/3); 
σct = Eci*εct; 
Fct = Integrate[σct*b, {x, 0, h - x0}]
MFct = Integrate[σct*b*x, {x, 0, h - x0}]
AS = 6912/10^6; 
Es = 2*10^11; 
Fst = AS*Es*(h - x0 - a)*β
MFst = Fsp*(h - x0 - a)
AS1 = 4471/10^6; 
Fsp = AS1*Es*(x0 - a)*β
MFsp = Fcp*(x0 - a)
Solve[{Fct + Fst - Fcp - Fsp == NF, 
  MFct + MFst + MFcp + MFsp == MF}, {x0, β}]
```

this can not be solved. I have tried the 'Solve', but the problem is the same, and showing information like this 'Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help'. I want to solve for 'x0' and 'β',but I can not find my mistakes, please help.

Comment: Hello there. This message is pretty much self-explanatory. You might want to look up [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) `>Details` to see how you can make exact numbers in your expressions. Even if you do that, `Solve` complains anew and does not want to derive an analytic solution. Alternatives: 1. [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) 2. [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) and of course 3. [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html). Good luck :-)

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that this problem has a symbolic solution?  If not try obtaining a numerical solution.  In addition, resolve the conditional statement in `Fcp`, for instance by `Fcp = Simplify[Integrate[\[Sigma]c*b, {x, 0, x0}], x0 \[Beta] < 0]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

R1 = 4.25 // Rationalize;
R2 = 3.85 // Rationalize;
h = 0.4 // Rationalize;
b = 1.6 // Rationalize;
a = 0.05 // Rationalize;
jiaodu = 56.8421*(Pi/180) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
g = 9.8 // Rationalize;
L1 = 2.026 // Rationalize;
L2 = 1.833 // Rationalize;
GS = 6.7*1000*g // Rationalize;
GP = 38.4*g // Rationalize;

xin = -((2*(Cos[jiaodu/2] - 1)*(R1^3 - R2^3))/
     (3*jiaodu*(R1^2 - R2^2)));
FX = ((3*GS + 6*GP)*L1)/(2*Sqrt[4*R2^2 - L1^2]); FY = (3*GS + 6*GP)/2;
M1 = FX*(R2 - Sqrt[R2^2 - L1^2/4] + h/2) + FY*(L1/2) // 
  Simplify; M2 = ((4*GS + 6*GP)*L2)/4; M3 = (xin*GS)/2;
MF = M1 - M2 + M3;
NF = FX;
Iz = (b*h^3)/12;
σ1 = (MF/Iz)*(h/2);
σ2 = NF/(b*h);
σ = σ1 - σ2;
If[σ > 0, Print["正负三角分布"]]

(* 正负三角分布 *)

Eci = 39.7*10^9 // Rationalize;
Ec1 = 24.7*10^9 // Rationalize;
ϵc1 = -2.6/10^3 // Rationalize;
ϵclim = -3.4/10^3 // Rationalize;
fcm = 63*10^6;
ϵc = x*β;
η = ϵc/ϵc1;
k = Eci/Ec1;
σc = (-fcm)*((k*η - η^2)/(1 + (k + 2)*η)) // Simplify;

Fcp = Integrate[σc*b, {x, 0, x0}];

MFcp = Integrate[σc*b*x, {x, 0, x0}];

ϵct = x*β;
EC0αE = 19400*10^6;
Eci = EC0αE*(fcm/(10*10^6))^(1/3);
σct = Eci*ϵct;

Fct = Integrate[σct*b, {x, 0, h - x0}];
MFct = Integrate[σct*b*x, {x, 0, h - x0}];

AS = 6912/10^6;
Es = 2*10^11;
Fst = AS*Es*(h - x0 - a)*β;
MFst = Fsp*(h - x0 - a);
AS1 = 4471/10^6;
Fsp = AS1*Es*(x0 - a)*β;
MFsp = Fcp*(x0 - a) // Simplify;

eqns =
  {Fct + Fst - Fcp - Fsp == NF, MFct + MFst + MFcp + MFsp == MF} //
   Simplify;
```

The equations require

```
eqns /. ConditionalExpression[expr_, cond_] :> cond // Union

(* {3211 Re[1/(x0 β)] > 4455000 || Re[1/(x0 β)] < 0 || 
  1/(x0 β) ∉ Reals} *)
```

Consequently, the product `(x0 β)` must be small. Minimizing the mean square error of the equations

```
{min, arg} = NMinimize[{Total[(Subtract @@@ (eqns // Normal))^2],
   3211/(x0 β) > 4455000, 0 < x0 < 1/4, 0 < β < 2*^-5}, {x0, β},
  WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {779669.091360002, {x0 -> 0.0716081874582401, β -> 
   8.18574703940298*10^-6}} *)

ContourPlot[eqns // Normal // Evaluate,
 {x0, 0, 1/4}, {β, 0, 2*^-5},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{x0, β} /. arg]},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {x0, β})]
```

[image]

Since the contours for the equations do not intersect, there does not appear to be a solution.

Comment: Such a pity that this answer is not upvoted and/or accepted. In spite of disproving the claim made in the OP, it is a full solution to the question!